# strange bug when adding numbers with nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

So this is most likely simple but I have spent all day trying different approaches and googling for solutions.

for some reason when I use + with 2 numbers instead of adding the numbers together node is joining the numbers.

```
  Company.findById(req.id, (err, doc) => {

      if (err) {
          callback(err, err);
      } else {

          var i = doc.TotalGranted; // i.e number value of 200
          var e = doc.TotalAvailable; // i.e number value of 200

          var newTotalgranted = i + req.newNumber; // i.e number value of 100
          var newAvailable = e - req.newNumber; // i.e number value of 100

          doc.TotalGranted= newTotalgranted;
          doc.TotalAvailable= newAvailable;

          doc.save((err, doc) => {
              if (err) {
                  callback(err, err);
              }
              callback(null, 'success');
          });
      }
  });
```

now instead of totalgranted  =  300 instead it equals 200,100

if it helps here is the relevant section of the returned document from mongo, these are not contained in an array

```
  TotalAvailable: 200,
  TotalGranted: 200,



newNumber: '100',
```

the new number is a string but its actually coming from a returned document as well. so maybe i need to convert the newNumber from a string i have tried this but can not work it out.

Comment: Replace `req.newNumber` usage with `Number(req.newNumber)`

Comment: What is the result of `i + parseInt(req.newNumber)`?

Comment: thanks for the fast replies guys checking now

Comment: *"when I use + with 2 numbers"* but you don't. A string is not a number! `newNumber: '100'`. And `someString + whatever` or `whatever + someString` performs a string concatenation. That's the expected behaviour, not a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you are right, your `req.newNumber` is a string so javascript by default performs string concatenation.
    Company.findById(req.id, (err, doc) => {

```
  if (err) {
      callback(err, err);
  } else {

      var i = doc.TotalGranted; // i.e number value of 200
      var e = doc.TotalAvailable; // i.e number value of 200
      var newNumber = parseInt(req.newNumber);  // or use Number(req.newNumber) or (req.newNumber * 1)
      var newTotalgranted = i + newNumber; // i.e number value of 100
      var newAvailable = e - newNumber; // i.e number value of 100

      doc.TotalGranted= newTotalgranted;
      doc.TotalAvailable= newAvailable;

      doc.save((err, doc) => {
          if (err) {
              callback(err, err);
          }
          callback(null, 'success');
      });
  }
});
```

this would work but best way will be to take a number from request parameter itself which will reduce your overhead of converting a string into an integer

You can read more about various strategy on number conversion from string [here](https://coderwall.com/p/5tlhmw/converting-strings-to-number-in-javascript-pitfalls)

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
Company.findById(req.id, (err, doc) => {

  if (err) {
      callback(err, err);
  } else {

      var i = doc.TotalGranted; // i.e number value of 200
      var e = doc.TotalAvailable; // i.e number value of 200

      var newTotalgranted = (i + (req.newNumber * 1)); // i.e number value of 100
      var newAvailable = (e - (req.newNumber * 1); // i.e number value of 100

      doc.TotalGranted= newTotalgranted;
      doc.TotalAvailable= newAvailable;

      doc.save((err, doc) => {
          if (err) {
              callback(err, err);
          }
          callback(null, 'success');
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: I think the problem in his code is neither `i` nor `e` but rather `req.newNumber`. See `newNumber: '100'`

Comment: yes, since it is being considered as `string` we can do a simple multiply of 1 to that will solve this. I made it for `i` and `e` which holds number already! Now changed.